# How to use grep with alternating part of the regular expression?

Tags: regex, grep, regex-alternation

I want to grep all dates in August or September (date format `mm/dd/yyyy` with leading zeroes).

I tried:

```
grep '0\(8\|9\)/[0-9][0-9]/2012'
```

But command prompt outputs:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` wants a regular expression and a file name. The error message looks like you somehow passed an invalid file name. Assuming the file containing the log entries is named `log`, try this;

```
grep '0[89]/[0-9][0-9]/2012' log
```

(I also tweaked your regex a bit.)

Comment: That worked perfectly, Thanks! This is what I used, **some command    |grep '0[89]/[0-3][0-9]/2012'**